# Having a set of default options to be passed to multiple initializers

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I'm building an app that allows users to select colors that will be applied to css. I'm using [spectrum.js](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) for the color picker. This is how you initialize the plugin:

```
$("#selector").spectrum();
```

You can pass in many options and I'm wanting to know if it is possible to make a global 'initializer' *(that might be the wrong term)* with a few default options that other 'initializers' can inherit from.

If so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.

```
var defaultOptions = {color: '#0', flat: true};
```

Now you can merge this default option with any local set of options and pass it to an initializer.

```
var myOptions = {showInput: true};

$("#selector").spectrum(meargeObjects(defaultOptions, myOptions));
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/4185234) answer provides a way to write the `meargeObjects` function.